# How to split of many date in one dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, date, split

I am working on a dataset in a csv format. The number of observations is "22255" and number of variables(columns) is "35". This dataset includes three variables "founded_at", "first_funding_at" and "last_funding_at" contain date.

This is sample of the dataset:

```
founded_at      first_funding_at    last_funding_at
12/1/2005          5/3/2011            5/3/2011
1/1/2007           8/1/2007            3/8/2008
7/1/2007           3/1/2008            3/1/2009
9/1/2007           10/1/2009           8/1/2010
4/2/2009           1/1/2009            6/27/2014
1/1/2010           11/6/2013           11/6/2013
```

I want to split all those date to "year", "week", "day", "quarter", "dayofweek", "weekofyear", "day_name" and "weekend". I tried to do this by the code below, but it doesn't work. I got this error "File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'feat'"

```
#Import packeges
import pandas as pd
# Read the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("Sales dataset - Vijay.csv", engine='python', parse_dates['founded_at','first_funding_at','last_funding_at'])

list1 = ["founded_at", "first_funding_at","last_funding_at"]

for feat in list1:
    #print (feat)
    df['Year'] = df[feat].dt.year
    df['Week'] = df[feat].dt.week
    df['Day'] =  df[feat].dt.day
    df['quarter'] = df['feat'].dt.quarter
    df['week_of_day'] = df['feat'].dt.dayofweek
    df['year_of_week'] = df['feat'].dt.weekofyear
    df['dayofweek_name'] = df['feat'].dt.day_name()
    df['weekend'] = np.where(df['feat'].isin(['Sunday','Saturday']),1,0)
```

I need really your help in fix this error.

Comment: Is there a column named `feat` in the dataset?  Or do you have a variable named `feat`. Your code is trying both ways.

Comment: No, the dataset contains only those variables:founded_at, first_funding_at and     last_funding_at

Comment: Could you please advise me what is the mistake in my code?

Comment: You're using the string `'feat'` instead of the variable `feat`

Comment: Also you are overriding the columns You should use something like `YEAR_FOUDNED`,`YEAR_FIRST_COUNDED` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code and the error, you're using a string instead of the loop variable:

```
for feat in list1:
    #print (feat)
    df['Year'] = df[feat].dt.year  # feat variable - correct
    df['Week'] = df[feat].dt.week
    df['Day'] =  df[feat].dt.day
    df['quarter'] = df['feat'].dt.quarter   # 'feat' string - wrong
    df['week_of_day'] = df['feat'].dt.dayofweek
    df['year_of_week'] = df['feat'].dt.weekofyear
    df['dayofweek_name'] = df['feat'].dt.day_name()
    df['weekend'] = np.where(df['feat'].isin(['Sunday','Saturday']),1,0)
```

It also looks like you're overwriting the same columns in the loop.

Full working code:

```
ss = '''
founded_at      first_funding_at    last_funding_at
12/1/2005          5/3/2011            5/3/2011
1/1/2007           8/1/2007            3/8/2008
7/1/2007           3/1/2008            3/1/2009
9/1/2007           10/1/2009           8/1/2010
4/2/2009           1/1/2009            6/27/2014
1/1/2010           11/6/2013           11/6/2013
'''.strip()

with open('data.csv','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file

############### main script ################

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Read the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", engine='python', parse_dates=True, delim_whitespace=True)

list1 = ["founded_at", "first_funding_at","last_funding_at"]

for feat in list1:
    df[feat] = pd.to_datetime(df[feat])
    #print (feat)
    df[feat + '_' + 'Year'] = df[feat].dt.year
    df[feat + '_' + 'Week'] = df[feat].dt.week
    df[feat + '_' + 'Day'] =  df[feat].dt.day
    df[feat + '_' + 'quarter'] = df[feat].dt.quarter
    df[feat + '_' + 'week_of_day'] = df[feat].dt.dayofweek
    df[feat + '_' + 'year_of_week'] = df[feat].dt.weekofyear
    df[feat + '_' + 'dayofweek_name'] = df[feat].dt.day_name()
    df[feat + '_' + 'weekend'] = np.where(df[feat].dt.day_name().isin(['Sunday','Saturday']),1,0)
    
print(df)
```

Comment: when I used variable feat, I got this error "File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-07 00:00:00"

Comment: i got the same error "File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\np_datetime.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-07 00:00:00"

Comment: after I remove "df[feat + '_' + 'weekend'] = np.where(df[feat].isin(['Sunday','Saturday']),1,0)".. It works well. I don't know why it doesn't work with this line code

Comment: Answer updated. Use `...np.where(df[feat].dt.day_name().isin(['....']),1,0)`